# Defining a placeholder tensor for one hot encoded data

Tags: python, tensorflow

Running below code :

```
 loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=training_outputs, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    
    # define placeholder for inputs to network
    xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2000])
    ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,81])
    
    
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for i in range(1000):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={xs:training_inputs, ys:training_outputs})
```

returns error :

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_150' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_150 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I think this is related to the format of `training_inputs` & `training_outputs` which is :

[image]

[image]

`training_inputs` & `training_outputs` are one hot encoded. But should each be of type `array([],[]....)` instead of `array([[],[],...])` ?

Answer (score 2):

> training_inputs & training_outputs are one hot encoded. But should each be of type array([],[]....) instead of array([[],[],...]) ?

No, the inputs and outputs look fine as they are.

The error says that you are not feeding a placeholder that is required for running the `optimizer` tensor. From the placeholder name in the error message (`Placeholder_150`) you can tell that you have created many placeholders.

One thing you need to know when you use a notebook in combination with tensorflow is that everytime you execute the cell with

```
xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2000])
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,81])
```

new placeholders will be added to the graph. The first time you execute it `"Placeholder_0"` and `"Placeholder_1"` will be added the second time `"Placeholder_2"` and `"Placeholder_3"`, and so on.

The issue is probably that `xs` or `ys` don't not refer to the same placeholder that was used to calculate `optimizer` anymore.

This can happen for instance if you first execute

```
 xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2000])
 ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,81])
```

then the part that builds `optimizer` from `xs` and `ys` and then execute

```
 xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2000])
 ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,81])
```

again before running the session.

**EDIT**:
It is also a mistake to create the placeholders after you create the `optimizer` tensor. As `optimizer` should depend on these placeholders. It should give an error the first time you run the notebook, but the second time it could cause the error you are getting.

Comment: where is the dependency between optimizer and xs,ys placeholders ? As xs,ys placeholders are just declared once within the notebook then how can they be referring to different placeholders ?

Comment: 1) I can't see that from the code in your question. But I would expect that `xs` is needed to calculate the `logits` and `ys` should be the supplied as the `onehot_labels argument` (I see that you use `training_outputs` there now at the moment. This is also a bug.). 

2) You can execute the cell of the placeholders multiple times. If `logits` was depended on the old value of `xs` you will get an error, see the example I gave in my answer.

Comment: You're using a jupyter-notebook to define your model, isn't it? Your `placeholder_150` looks like you're running the placeholder definition again and again. Just try restarting the notebook and sequentially run every single step. Something could change. Give it a try

Comment: @nessuno That's what my answer says :) Though, just restarting the notebook will probably not work as the placeholders are defined after the `optimizer` tensor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being confused with the loss calculation

```
# Here onehot_labels is not exactly the training outputs data, but the ground truths labels placeholder <ys> of your training data <xs>
# this line should be replaced with 
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=training_outputs, logits=logits)
# this one
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=ys, logits=logits)
```